Categorical lens on theory interpretation

What are some categorical takes on the notion of theory interpretation?

Reading this question it sounds like mutual interpretation corresponds to equivalence of categories (returning an isomorphic object instead of exactly the same object), whereas bi-interpretation sounds like an isomorphism of categories (returning exactly the same object). What would an adjunction correspond to in this view? Does institution theory have anything to say? Any pointers are appreciated.

Interpretations are a certain kind of functor between the classifying topoi of theories.

Biinterpretability corresponds to a certain kind of equivalence of categories. I'm not sure whether mutual interpretability is actually enough.

There is something subtle about these facts in relation to the linked question though, which is that mutual interpretability of set theories doesn't necessarily induce an equivalence of their (internal) categories of sets.

I think Visser's paper Categories of theories and interpretations is relevant.

There's a lot of potential for confusion in this area because certain ideas occur at two different levels of abstraction. There's also a lot of different approaches people have developed in categorical logic, so it can be a little hard to keep track of all of them and I'm not sure I can personally say I grasp them all.

In one of the general pictures of categorical logic, first-order theories correspond to syntactic categories. These are a categorical presentation of the category of definable sets in a first-order theory (with definable maps as morphisms).
Given a syntactic category, one can take the pretopos completion, which gives a pretopos, naturally enough. This is essentially the same thing as what model theorists call the $T^{\mathrm{eq}}$ construction in which you explicitly add in what are called imaginary sorts.
Interpretations of theories can fairly naturally be phrased in terms of these pretopoi. An interpretation of $T_0$ in $T_1$ is a functor from the pretopos associated to $T_0$ to the pretopos associated to $T_1$ satisfying a certain compatibility condition (which corresponds to inducing a Boolean algebra homomorphism on the Lindenbaum–Tarski algebra of each object/sort).
If you go one step further and consider the full topos of sheaves (with the coherent topology) on these pretopoi, these interpretation functors correspond to certain special geometric morphisms.
As you alluded to in your question, this is not the only approach to categorical logic that exists in the literature. There's institutions (part of institution-independent model theory) and (Boolean) hyperdoctrines. I think there's probably a relationship between the (pre-)topos-theoretic picture and these others, but I don't know it at the moment.

Now, the reason I said there's potential for confusion is that when talking about interpretations of set theories, there's really two categories at play: There's the category of definable classes (which you would normally call definable sets) which is what the previous picture from categorical logic is all about, but then there's also the actual category of sets in a given model of the theory. Since topos theory is often described as an equivalent of set theory, this gets particularly confusing if you consider the classifying topos of (a certain Morleyization of) $\mathsf{ZFC}$. In this situation there's really two relevant set-theory-like objects, one inside the other.
Usually (but not always) an interpretation $I$ of one set theory $T_0$ in another $T_1$ will induce a functor from the category of sets in the model $I(M) \models T_0$ to the category of sets in the model $M \models T_1$ (where $I(M)$ is the model of $T_0$ produced by applying the interpretation of $T_0$ to $M$). Often (but again not always) this will give equivalences of categories in the case of mutual interpretations.
$\mathsf{ZF}$ is somewhat special in that biinterpretations between models induce exact on-the-nose isomorphism between them. A similar phenomenon happens with $\mathsf{PA}$.
